# Turning mysql query into prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to turn the below query into a prepared statement, but I'm having no luck so far. I've attached one of my attempts. The idea is I'm using this to check how many rows are returned using mysqli_num_rows afterward.

```
 $sql2=mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT address FROM member WHERE address='".$address."'");
```

This is my attempt at creating a prepared statement.

```
$ustmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT username FROM member WHERE username = ?");
$ustmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$sql2 = $ustmt->execute();
```

Is this correct? And if so, how do I then check the number of rows returned into $sql2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your preparation and execution is correct.

The execute call returns a `boolean` value, which will be `true` if successful else `false` (if `false`, the `$stmt->error` property will be set with error message).
This is worth checking before continuing, cause if its false, there will be no result.
Same with the preparation, if the `$mysqli->prepare(...)` call returns false, the `$mysqli->error` will be set with the error message.

After execution, you can fetch the number of affected rows by either the `$num_rows` property, in case its a `SELECT` statement, or the `$affected_rows` property in other cases.

```
echo $stmt->num_rows;
```

Or, you can fetch the [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object from the statement with the `get_result()` method.
The `mysqli_result` object contains the public field `$num_rows`, so you can check row count by:

```
$res = $stmt->get_result();
echo $res->num_rows;
```

For other methods in the `mysqli_result` object, i recommend checking the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).

Comment: Hi, I have been trying your method, but after executing $sql2 only holds the value 1, even if it returns 0 rows. mysqli_num_rows doesn't do anything and I can't use get_result, as my webspace doesn't have the appropriate driver.

Comment: Your `$sql2` variable is 1, which is equal to `true`. That means that the `execute` call was successful. After that, you need to fetch the number of rows from the stmt object: `$ustmt->num_rows;`.

Comment: Oh brilliant! I'm so dense! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problems, happy to help. :)